# Why does Android Firebase skip authentication activities

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing Firebase email/password authentication into my new android app.

The app works fine for the most part, except that when the user clicks on one of the two the buttons login or registration, the app skips the supposed activity, login or registration, and goes straight into mainActivity.

This is how I have wrote the intent to open next activity:-

```
mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseLogin.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;}});
```

There are two errors I found in debugging which might be relevant:-

> W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized
>   classloader  W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found.

As well as:-

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.android.gms.crash not found.

Based on answers to similar issues as mine I have :

- checked with the firebase assistant it says I'm connected.

  [image: Firebase Assistant]
- checked that in the firebase console I have enabled email/Password login
- checked on my device and an emulator and on both it acted the same
- checked that I use the latest 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
- checked that the google play services are fine 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
- even added into manifest request for internet permission
- implemented firebases crashylytics and it doesn't catch this
- re-added the google.services.json file and then build/rebuild the project

**EDIT** ( Upon request the registrationActivity and logcat  ) :

registrationActivity's onCreate :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        fireBaseStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;}};

   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(fireBaseStateListener);
    }
```

Logcat :

```
11-23 11:58:59.652 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-23 11:59:00.016 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
11-23 11:59:00.020 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-23 11:59:00.027 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-23 11:59:00.048 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
11-23 11:59:00.091 12880-12914/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-23 11:59:00.104 12880-12914/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
11-23 11:59:00.104 12880-12914/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
11-23 11:59:00.118 12880-12917/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
11-23 11:59:00.118 12880-12917/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
11-23 11:59:00.148 12880-12917/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
11-23 11:59:00.156 12880-12917/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:10
11-23 11:59:00.157 12880-12917/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 10
11-23 11:59:00.162 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -385218149
11-23 11:59:00.171 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
11-23 11:59:00.172 12880-12880/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
11-23 11:59:00.205 12880-12921/com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike V/FA: Collection enabled
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for 4 days now.

Comment: remove the `return`

Comment: @PeterHaddad I did, Still the same result

Comment: I'd also appriciate comments on the formating of my question, did I post enough relevent info, should I post more code and if possible which ? 
I'd be immensilly grateful if someone with more experience could just point me what should I research or where should i look for the solution.

Comment: is your app crashing? and maybe show the full logcat to see the problem there

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thank you for your suggestions. 
No the app doesn't crash, it just skips an activity. I've posted more of the logcat like you've suggested. I'm worried if I post the full logcat i'll get downvoted and banned.

Comment: @FarisKapo make rules public from firebase console will solve your problem

Comment: @WaleedAsim Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried this, but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Can you please post you RegistrationActivity's onCreate code here

Comment: @FarisKapo change your layout seems like you call login layout instead of registration layout

Comment: @Rahul I've posted the RegistrationActivity's onCreate code

Comment: you need to check if current user is available or not.if available then proceed to next screen else stay here in this screen.... or simply comment "startActivity(intent);" this line

Comment: @FarisKapo did you check your layouts name?

Comment: @WaleedAsim Yes thank you Waleed for showing me that, I've changed it now.

Comment: @FarisKapo seems like you call wrong layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes its going directly to mainactivity because of this:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    fireBaseStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;}};

 @Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      mAuth.addAuthStateListener(fireBaseStateListener);
   }
```

`onStart` this is done: `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(fireBaseStateListener);`

So it is entering the Listener and since you have this in your code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivty(intent);
```

it is going directly to MainActivity.class

do this:

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
      if(user!=null){ //if user is signed in
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
         else{
               Log.i("sign in", not signed in);
            }};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I finally feel a little bit less loss around this issue. But could you please elaborate what exactly do I need to change, since I only understand that there is something wrong there and not quite how to fix it. I apologize if i'm asking too much and again thank you for you time.

Comment: yes I edited it, it should check now if the user is signed in then it goes to mainActivity skipping registrationactivity, if not it stays in registrationActivity

Comment: Took me a while to implement it sorry, but it works finally. Thank you a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem,  happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement `Shared Preferences`?
Perhaps due to `Shared Preference` if you implement this for `user session`.
if you didn't implement
then  try copy your code from `RegistrationActivity.java` then create new `Activity` and paste into there.